# (Java) How to access, add, get class object in ArrayList?

Tags: java

Here is my tiny code. when I try to sysout list.get(i) at last. It always showing wrong data, even get(0) isn't the 0,0 data add at first. But when I sysout the y_pos and x_pos is correct. So who can help or guide me how to use it correctly?
* The wrong data mean : all of the data is same for i~list.length *

```
import java.util.*;

class POS{
    int x_pos, y_pos;

    public void setpos(int x, int y){
        this.x_pos = x;
        this.y_pos = y;
    }
}

class Solution {
    public int solution(String dirs) {
        int answer = 0;
        ArrayList<POS> list = new ArrayList<POS>();
        POS pos = new POS();
        int x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0;
        pos.setpos(0,0);
        list.add(pos);

        for(int i=0; i<dirs.length(); ++i)
        {
            switch(dirs.charAt(i)){
                case 'L' : x_pos = x_pos - 1; break;
                case 'R' : x_pos = x_pos + 1; break;
                case 'U' : y_pos = y_pos + 1; break;
                case 'D' : y_pos = y_pos - 1; break;
            }
            if(x_pos < -5 || x_pos > 5 || y_pos < -5 || y_pos > 5) continue;
            else{
                pos.setpos(x_pos,y_pos);
                list.add(pos);
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); ++i){
            System.out.println(list.get(i).x_pos + " " + list.get(i).y_pos);
        }

        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: "It always showing wrong data" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What data* is it showing? Why is that data "wrong data"? What would be "right data"?

Comment: thx for comment. specific wrong data precises added.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to new pos in the property of the second set pos (that is in the for loop), otherwise the data of pos will change when you set, but the pointers of the elements in the list all point to the original pos object, resulting in the final When you use sysout, all data in the list are the data you set last

Comment: 除非你不用泛型list，否则我感觉你只能这样去new pos了

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new object of POS before adding to list(assuming you want list of POS objects)

Answer (score 0):

You need to new pos in the property of the second set pos (that is in the for loop), otherwise the data of pos will change when you set, but the pointers of the elements in the list all point to the original pos object, resulting in the final When you use sysout, all data in the list are the data you set last.
As far as my current ability knows, when you want to add elements using a generic list, you can only do this. If there is a better operation method, I hope to inform.